# Using getAttribute with addEventListener in Javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, getattribute

In javascript I create some html to display 5 game characters in a div class named 'characters':

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('characters');
for(var i in characters){
    // build the character list
    element[0].innerHTML += '<div class="char-container"><img 
    src="'+characters[i].img.default+'" alt="'+characters[i].name+'">
    <h2>'+characters[i].name+'</h2><span class="type '+characters[i].type+'">
    </span></div>';
}
```

In Javascript I add a click event that i want to return the game character name:

```
var element = document.querySelectorAll ('.characters, .char-container');
let index = 0;
console.log ("element "+element.length);
for( index=0; index < element.length; index++ ) {
    clickerFn = function(){
        var attribute = (this).getAttribute('h2');
        alert("Hello World! +name "+attribute);
    }
    element[index].addEventListener('click', clickerFn, false);
} // for
```

This returns a null :-(

Question: in Javascript how do I use getAttribute to get 'character.name' ( what's contained in

Thanks
steve

Comment: @T.J.Crowder — Grandchild I think.

Comment: @Quentin: Yeah, I think so.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `h2` is **not an attribute**. `<h2>` is an **element**.

```
this.querySelector('h2').textContent;
```

See also:

- [Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Attribute)
- [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Element)
- [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)
- [type selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors)
- [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)